# Get data of multiple column with same foreign key in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two table first one is ReservationVehicleDetail = RVD, and the second one is Employee = EMP

In RVD has two column PrimaryDriverId and SecondaryDriverId both have mapped to EmployeeId of EMP table

My question is how to get data of Employee table using those two Ids.

Here is my code:

```
 vm.BookVehicleDetailList = db.ReservationVehicleDetails.Where(x => x.ReservationId == vm.ReservationId && x.Status == Constant.ACTIVE).Select(v => new BookVehicleDetailModel()
                        {
                            VehicleImageURL = v.Vehicle.PictureURL,
                            IsDutySlipClosed = v.IsDutySlipClosed.HasValue ? v.IsDutySlipClosed.Value : false,
                            ReservationVehicleDetailId = v.ReservationVehicleDetailIId,
                            VehicleId = v.VehicleId.HasValue ? v.VehicleId.Value : 0,
                            VehicleCategory = v.VehicleCategory,
                            IsAC = v.IsAC,
                            ACorNonAC = v.IsAC ? "AC" : "Non AC",
                            FuelType = v.FuelType,
                            SeatingCapacity = v.Capacity,
                            RegistrationNumber = v.RegistrationNumber,
                            PrimaryDriverId = v.PrimaryDriverId.HasValue ? v.PrimaryDriverId.Value : 0,
                            PrimaryDriverName = v.PrimaryDriverId.HasValue ? v.Employee.FirstName : v.PrimaryDriverName,
                            SecondaryDriverId = v.SecondaryDriverId.HasValue ? v.SecondaryDriverId.Value : 0,
                            SecondaryDriverName = v.SecondaryDriverId.HasValue ? v.Employee.FirstName : v.SecondaryDriverName,
                            TariffType = v.TariffType,
                            DailyMinimumDistance = v.DailyMinimumDistance.HasValue ? v.DailyMinimumDistance.Value : 0,
                            TariffPerUnitDistance = v.TariffPerUnitDistance.HasValue ? v.TariffPerUnitDistance.Value : 0,
                            ExternalCompanyName = v.ExternalCompanyName,
                            StartDistanceReading = v.StartDistanceReading.HasValue ? v.StartDistanceReading.Value : 0,
                            EndDistanceReading = v.EndDistanceReading.HasValue ? v.EndDistanceReading.Value : 0,
                            GarageDistanceReading = v.GarageDistanceReading.HasValue ? v.GarageDistanceReading.Value : 0,
                            GrossTariff = v.GrossTariff.HasValue ? v.GrossTariff.Value : 0,
                            Distance = (v.StartDistanceReading.HasValue ? v.StartDistanceReading.Value : 0) + " - " + (v.EndDistanceReading.HasValue ? v.EndDistanceReading.Value : 0) + " - " + (v.GarageDistanceReading.HasValue ? v.GarageDistanceReading.Value : 0) + " (" + ((v.EndDistanceReading.HasValue ? v.EndDistanceReading.Value : 0) - (v.StartDistanceReading.HasValue ? v.StartDistanceReading.Value : 0) + (v.GarageDistanceReading.HasValue ? v.GarageDistanceReading.Value : 0)) + " KM)",
                        }).ToList();
```

Right now data return based on the first PrimaryDriverId means PrimaryDriverId and SecodaryDriverId both are different but PrimaryDriverName and SecondaryDriverName both are same after executing the query.

So how to solve this issue.

Comment: what exactly is v.SecondaryDriverName and v.PrimaryDriverName ?

Comment: It's just EmployeeName based of the PrimaryDriverId and SecondaryDriverId. i.e. PrimaryDriverId  = 10 and SecondaryDriverId = 15 then  PrimaryDriverName should be 'ABC' and SecondaryDriverName should be 'XYZ' but right now I get 'ABC' for both.

Comment: I hope you should have two references in your ReservationVehicleDetails class one for PrimaryDriver and Second for SecondaryDriver, right?

Comment: No both references to the same column EmplyoeeId of Employee table.

Comment: Try out the below solution and let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: If neither of the answers below resolve your issue then you may want to add your model code to the question. For instance I don't understand why RVD has a `SecondaryDriverName`, this is in your Employee table?

Answer (score 1):

Your `v.employee` is only related to one Employee. So you get the same Employee object.

I am presuming you have a model that looks something like this:

```
public class RVD
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; } //This will only link to one Employee
    public int PrimaryDriverId { get; set; }
    public int SecondaryDriverId { get; set; }
}
```

You can either look at changing the Linq to add a join so that you can map RVD to two different employees:

e.g.

```
var result = (from r in rvds
                        join e1 in emps on r.PrimaryDriverId equals e1.Id
                        join e2 in emps on r.SecondaryDriverId equals e2.Id
                        where r.Id == 1
                        select new
                        {
                            PrimaryDriverName = e1.Name,
                            SecondaryDriverName = e2.Name
                        }).ToList();
```

Or you can update your model.

e.g.

```
public class RVD
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Emp PrimaryDriver { get; set; }
    public Emp SecondaryDriver { get; set; }
}

public class Emp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var emp1 = new Emp() { Id = 1, Name = "John" };
var emp2 = new Emp() { Id = 2, Name = "Dave" };

var rvd = new RVD() { Id = 1, PrimaryDriver = emp1, SecondaryDriver = emp2 };

List<RVD> rvds = new List<RVD>();
rvds.Add(rvd);


var result  = rvds.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => new
{
    PrimaryDriverName = x.PrimaryDriver.Name,
    SecondaryDriverName = x.SecondaryDriver.Name,

}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess You might have put this conditions wrong.

```
PrimaryDriverName = v.PrimaryDriverId.HasValue ? v.Employee.FirstName : v.PrimaryDriverName,

SecondaryDriverName = v.SecondaryDriverId.HasValue ? v.Employee.FirstName : v.SecondaryDriverName
```

I guess you want to assign the Driver Name if the `Id` is present else you want to assign the Employee.FirstName but it seems like you are assigning the Employee.FirstName when you have `Id's` present for both primary as well as the secondary driver.

I guess you should try switching the condition as below.

```
PrimaryDriverName = v.PrimaryDriverId.HasValue ? v.PrimaryDriverName : v.Employee.FirstName,

SecondaryDriverName = v.SecondaryDriverId.HasValue ? v.SecondaryDriverName : v.Employee.FirstName,
```